# My pug doesn’t eat until fed by hand

Tags: dogs, feeding

My dog does not take a single bite of his food until he is hand fed and, since yesterday, he has stopped eating anything whether hand fed or not. I'm not able to understand what to do and even the vets said that there is no alternative available other than trying changing his dog food. Unfortunately, even that did not work out.

Comment: Can you please provide more details like the age of your dog, how long this has been going on, if there are any other behavioral/physical changes, etc?

Comment: Take him to the vet.